# How to make Jquery UI autocomplete work on child elements of a content editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a content editable **div** with a **span** child element that is also content editable. Autocomplete suggestions seem to work on the parent element, but not on the child element. This is using jquery ui's autocomplete widget.
**HTML:**

```
<div id="main" contenteditable="true">
    <span id="sub" contenteditable="true"></span>
</div>
```

**JS:**
This works if I set autocomplete to the parent -
`$('#main').autocomplete({ source = ["Tomato", "Potato", "Peas"]});`

However, this does not seem to work for the child -
`$('#sub').autocomplete({ source = ["Tomato", "Potato", "Peas"]});`

Note: I know that I am typing inside the span tag as I am shifting the caret into the tag using some javascript.

I would like suggestions to appear only for the span as I am trying to implement a tagging system similar to Facebook's comment system. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: working code snippet or fiddle will be highly helpful here.

Comment: This is the closest I could get to what I want to accomplish https://fiddle.jshell.net/88m02oug/2/

Comment: the issue is occurring because as soon as you start typing in into the red (inner `span` element) area; your `span` element is getting destroyed by the text you just typed-in. Hence `autocomplete` is not firing up. What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: My requirement is similar to how you type @ in Facebook's comment and receive suggestions of people you can tag.

Comment: @wolf3D I would suggest replacing the `div` with a `input` upon clicking to edit. Will look at the content editable, but autoComplete may not like it.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best example, but you can see how `main2` works differently than `main1` here:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Twisty/o1f0wuph/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main1" contenteditable="true">
  Type Here parent suggestions
  <span contenteditable="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="main2-wrapper">
  <div id="main2" contenteditable="true" data-value="" data-placeholder="Type Here">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main1 {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}

.main2-wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var stuff = [
    "Tomato",
    "Potato",
    "Peas"
  ];
  $('#main1').autocomplete({
    source: stuff
  });
  $("#main2").text($("#main2").data("placeholder"));
  $("#main2").blur(function() {
      var v = $(this).text();
      var p = $(this).data("placeholder");
      $(this).data("value", v);
      if (v === "") {
        $(this).text($(this).data("placeholder"));
      }
    })
    .focus(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == $(this).data("placeholder")) {
        $(this).text("");
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      source: stuff,
      minLength: 3
    });
});
```

It should not matter if you're using `div` versus `span`, I just prefer `div`. I applied the styling to the wrapper. I wasn't sure if the background color should remain when typing or not.

I added a bit to make it more like a text field, where it cleared out the text to allow the user to enter their text. <strike>Might go back and only do this for the placeholder text so that it doesn't remove whatever they had previously typed.</strike>